# Factorization problem and integer solutions

Tags: polynomials

> Find all ordered pairs of integer solutions $(x, y)$ such that $2^x+1 = y^2$

So I see that we can get $2^x=(y+1)(y-1)$ and from here we see that the right hand side has to be a power of two. I found this problem online and it stated that the difference $(y+1)-(y-1)$ has to be $2$, which i don't really see.

If we take the case $2^2 = (y+1)(y-1)$, then shouldn't the difference be equal to $0$?

Comment: FYI, this is a particular, and relatively simple, case of the more general [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tavish's answer is great, but I'd like to add some context as to how to actually solve the problem. Your factorization of the equation into $2^x=(y-1)(y+1)$ is great. From here, we know that $y-1$ and $y+1$ are both powers of $2$.

And, since the difference of $y+1-(y-1)$ is $2$, there is exactly one solution, since only two powers of two are exactly $2$ apart. (These are $2,4$)

So, the only solution is $(3,3)$.

Answer (score 0):

$(y+1)-(y-1) = y +1 - y +1 =2$

No, you cannot get both $y-1$ and $y+1$ to equal $2$. There would be no solutions when $x=2$.